# Wordpress REST API, run long background job

Tags: plugin-development

I have own custom Rest API's.
I would like to make one longer job there which can take a few minutes.
It is course too long to wait for api response.
I would like to run this job in background, return meantime 200 to the user.
When job will finish, will save results to the DB.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Sounds like the REST API would be writing to a **job queue** where the first-in is first-out. The jobs are worked on automatically according to that order. If the user needs the background data, then it could be e.g. emailed to the user when it's ready with a given url to data. Implementing such a system in detail is probably out of scope here.

Comment: I mean smth like in java/scala you have, threads, akka etc. you just run process in anotther thread. Async rest apis.

Comment: only cron job is the solution ?

Comment: or can be by hooks ? for example I will save_post, which is connected the some hook, hooks fires up after post saved. I am not sure how exactly it works in the background, I am new to WP :)

Comment: Cron would most likely work well for periodically crunching through the jobs, then there are solutions like (I've not tested them though) [WP-Minions](https://github.com/10up/WP-Minions), [WP Background Processing](https://github.com/A5hleyRich/wp-background-processing,) [Async Background Processing](https://github.com/stephenharris/async-batch-processing) with an [example](https://github.com/stephenharris/async-batch-processing-example/blob/master/async-batch-processing-example.php) that might be useful to you.

Comment: WP Background Processing has a new github url : https://github.com/deliciousbrains/wp-background-processing
There is also a blog post about it from its author: https://deliciousbrains.com/background-processing-wordpress/